# trying to generate deep complex sql queries dynamically

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, dynamicquery

I am trying to construct a Dynamic SQL query using multiple filter conditions (where clause) which can get complex and deeper with sub-queries and joins.

I have already build a basic structure for this using FilterClass

```
{
  Column,
  Operator,
  Value
}
```

But this is way limited as I am not able to use this for select or update. The app does not uses any kind of ORM as of now for dynamic query generation.

I am trying to add Group condition by having of list of filter, but that is also not generating complex queries.

example query

```
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE COL IN (VALUES)) AND COL2 = SOMEVAL OR (COL2 = SOMEANOTHERVAL)
```

How can I extend above to generate complex queries or is there any tool which does this already(as I should not be reinventing the wheel)

Comment: No, no, no, no, no! Don't do dynamic queries on purpose. Do it if you have no other choice due to bad code.

Comment: _"is there any tool which does this already(as I should not be reinventing the wheel)"_ Entity Framework?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Comment: @Diado Application does not use any ORM. As far as I understand, EF uses only static tables, but in my requirement, mostly there are dynamic tables except few static tables.

Comment: Database tables, that do not exist "forever" are kind of rare. Is the only thing your application knows about the Database is "a database exists" ? No knowledge of any structures ? The database is completely anonymous ?